# PIN Block format 01 Progress 4gl

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

How can I implement PIN Block Format 01? so I could get the output like this:

```
accnum            pin1   pin2
----------------  -----  ----------------
6034000001234562  92389  0592789FFFEDCBA9
```

I don't know how to implement xor bitwise.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not built-in XOR.  However:

[logical XOR operator in Progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25200708/logical-xor-operator-in-progress)

might be helpful.

For PIN Block formats there are many resources.  This might be a good place to start:

https://www.eftlab.co.uk/index.php/site-map/knowledge-base/261-complete-list-of-pin-blocks-in-payments

Comment: No, i still get an error of my code. I don't know why

Comment: I've fixed my code problem, thank you sir for your attention. Could you tell me how can I learn about logic and progress 4gl to increase my knowledge?

Comment: "thank you" is usually expressed via an up vote and by accepting the answer.  Learning often happens by reading the documentation which can be found at: https://community.progress.com/technicalusers/w/openedgegeneral/1329.openedge-product-documentation-overview.aspx or by participating in forums such as http://progresstalk.com or https://community.progress.com and by attending user group meetings: http://pugchallenge.org